# Why does a combination of two JPQL queries that work separately do not work when combined?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In a spring-boot project useing hibernate I want to create a query that returns all the actions that have dates between dates and ByMethodPaymentId.
The entity class:

```
    @Entity
    public class Action {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @Valid
    private MethodPayment methodPayment;
    //constructor....getter... setter...
```

this the repository to action:

```
   @Repository
    public interface ActionRepository extends JpaRepository<Action, Long>{

    // Dont works
    Collection<Action> findByMethodPaymentIdAndByDateBetween(long methodPaymentId,Date startDate, Date endDate );
    // works    
    Collection<Action> findByMethodPaymentId(long methodPaymentId);
    // works
    Collection<Action> findByDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

Why do the last two queries work but the first one that is a combination of both does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to mention `By` again when using `JPQL`, so the method will be like

```java
Collection<Action> findByMethodPaymentIdAndDateBetween(long methodPaymentId,Date startDate, Date endDate );
```

Try this.

Answer (score 2):

Just `Remove` the `By` after `And`

Change

```
findByMethodPaymentIdAndByDateBetween()
```

To

```
findByMethodPaymentIdAndDateBetween()
```

Final Query

```
Collection<Action> findByMethodPaymentIdAndDateBetween(long methodPaymentId,Date startDate, Date endDate );
```

*Multiple And/OR*

```
findByFirstParameterAndSecondeParameterORThirdParameter(...)
```